# What's the difference between "called" , "had called" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

> When he...............her as a cheater, she complained him to the master.

A) had called
B) called
C) has called
D) was called

**In the module, the correct answer is B), but I didn't grasp it well.**

Comment: _Called_ in the simple past tense matches _complained_ in the second half of the sentence. (If you have copied it accurately, there are two errors in the sentence - it should be _called her a cheater_ and _complained about him_.)

Comment: The original sentence is clearly ungrammatical, see Kate Bunting's comment. I would check very carefully that you copied it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

B) **called**

He called- simple past tense

She complained- simple past tense

He had called- past perfect tense

When one action comes straight after another, we use the simple past tense for both. We use *when* to mean ‘(at) the time that’.

When he **called** ... she **complained**...

We can use the past perfect to say that one thing finished and then something else happened.

[ ...*called her* a ...(NOT called her as a...)

...*complained about* him (NOT complained him) ]